# PHPExcel + SetReadFilter() + GetHighestRow()

Tags: phpexcel

Добрый день!
Использую PHPExcel для большого файла, размером около 20Мб, чтобы обойти ограничение по памяти, приходится использовать SetReadFilter и ChunkReadFilter для чтения по кускам. Но в этом случае определения количества строк на листе (GetHighestRow) не работает.
Т.е. работает, но всегда равно числу строк в отобранном куске файла (т.е. если читаю по 100 строк, оно всегда 100, если читать по 10 - всегда 10).
Есть ли возможность все-таки получить полное количество строк на листе?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение:

```
$FilePath = PATH_TO_FILE;
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::CreateReaderForFile($FilePath);
$arSheetsInfo = $objReader->ListWorksheetInfo($FilePath);
print_r($arSheetsInfo);
```